# Why does MPI_REDUCE returns a syntax error at compile time?

Tags: fortran, mpi, hpc

I haven't coded in Fortran since my college days in the late 70's (and that was with punch cards!), but now I am trying to learn how to use MPI with the language. I am getting a syntax error in the call to MPI_REDUCE but I can't figure out why. I just know I am missing something simple.

```
C Test program

      program pi_reduce
      include 'mpif.h'

      double precision PI25DT
      parameter (PI25DT = 3.141592535897932384662643d0)
      double precision mypi, pi, h, sum, x, f, a
      integer n, myid, numprocs, i, ierr
      f(a) = 4.d0/(1.d0 + a*a)

      call MPI_INIT(ierr)
      call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myid, ierr)
      call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, numprocs, ierr)
      do
        if (myid .eq. 0) then
          print *, 'Enter the number of intervals: (0 quits) '
          read(*,*) n
        endif
        call MPI_BCAST(n, 1, MPI_INTEGER, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
        if (n .le. 0) exit
        h = 1.0d0/n
        sum = 0.0d0
        do i = myid + 1, n, numprocs
          x = h * (dble(i) - 0.5d0)
          sum = sum + f(x)
        enddo
        mypi = h * sum
        call MPI_REDUCE(mypi, pi, 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
        if (myid .eq. 0) then
          print *, 'pi is ', pi, ' Error is', abs(pi-PI25DT)
        endif
      enddo
      call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)
      end
```

Comment: At first, you should replace the "legacy" `include 'mpif.h'` by `use mpi` immediately followed by `implicit none`. If that does not point you to the error, then please update your question with the new code and the full error message.

Comment: Double check the offending line is not longer than allowed (e.g. 72 columns in fixed-form source files)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet include 'mpif.h' and use mpi make no difference. Neither does the implicit none, but the 72 char truncation is right on the money. Strangely, using & to continue the rest of the line on the next one also throws an error. I think I'll just dump this Fortran thing and use a more modern language like C or Python.

Comment: Did you (also) put a continuation character at column 6? Anyway, don't throw the baby out with the bathwater. Fortran 90 and later is all you need (rename you `.F` file into a `.f90`, change the first line (comment) and you should be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments one of your lines is too long. With gfortran at least if you turn warnings up to the max (as you should if developing code) you get a more informative message

```
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ mpif90 --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ian@eris:~/work/stack$ mpif90 -O -fcheck=all -std=f2008 -Wall -Wextra long.f 
long.f:8:72:

       f(a) = 4.d0/(1.d0 + a*a)
                                                                        1
Warning: Obsolescent feature: Statement function at (1)
long.f:27:72:

         call MPI_REDUCE(mypi, pi, 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
                                                                        1
Warning: Line truncated at (1) [-Wline-truncation]
long.f:27:72:

         call MPI_REDUCE(mypi, pi, 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
                                                                        1
Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1)
```

I suggest you move the the "new" (i.e. available for 30 years) free format which is more flexible than the archaic punch card based form. In fact in general it would be a great opportunity to learn modern, safer practices than what you used all those years ago (I am guessing from what you say we are of a very similar vintage). Here's a somewhat modernised version of your code

```
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ cat long.f90
program pi_reduce

  Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only :  wp => real64
  ! Even better Use mpi_f08
  Use            :: mpi, Only : mpi_init, mpi_comm_rank, mpi_comm_size, mpi_reduce, &
       MPI_INTEGER, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_SUM

  Implicit None
  
  Real( wp ), Parameter :: PI25DT = 3.141592535897932384662643_wp

  Real( wp ) :: mypi, pi, h, sum, x
  integer    :: n, myid, numprocs, i, ierr

  call MPI_INIT(ierr)
  call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myid, ierr)
  call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, numprocs, ierr)
  do
     if (myid == 0) then
        print *, 'Enter the number of intervals: (0 quits) '
        read(*,*) n
     endif
     call MPI_BCAST(n, 1, MPI_INTEGER, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
     if (n .le. 0) exit
     h = 1.0_wp/n
     sum = 0.0_wp
     do i = myid + 1, n, numprocs
        x = h * ( Real( i , wp ) - 0.5_wp)
        sum = sum + f(x)
     enddo
     mypi = h * sum
     call MPI_REDUCE(mypi, pi, 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
     if (myid .eq. 0) then
        print *, 'pi is ', pi, ' Error is', abs(pi-PI25DT)
     endif
  enddo
  call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)

Contains

  Pure Function f( a ) 

    Use, Intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, Only :  wp => real64

    Implicit None

    Real( wp ) :: f

    Real( wp ), Intent( In ) :: a

    f = 4.0_wp / ( 1.0_wp + a * a )
    
  End Function f
  
end program pi_reduce
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ mpif90 --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ian@eris:~/work/stack$ mpif90 -O -fcheck=all -std=f2008 -Wall -Wextra long.f90
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ mpirun -np 8 ./a.out
 Enter the number of intervals: (0 quits) 
345435
 pi is    3.1415926535904788       Error is   1.1769254637528093E-007
 Enter the number of intervals: (0 quits) 
0
ian@eris:~/work/stack$
```

Comment: Thanks, this is just an example, right out of the "Using MPI" textbook v3 from MIT Press., figure 3.2. I think I bought the wrong book, and should be using C or Python.

Comment: That was published in 1994 which is why it is showing it age. For high performance numerical work IMO Fortran, especially if your are using Fortran 2003 or later, is still very much the way to go, certainly C has no advantage that I can see. Python can be easier to get things going, but don't expect the same performance.

Comment: My goal is to learn to use MPI, not high performance numerical work. C doesn't have the archaic my-way-or-the-highway declaration rules and lack of backwards compatibility that F90 has, and Python is the language of choice for other work such as bioinformatics. Once I understand how MPI works I may come back to Fortran if a customer requires it. Thanks!